# Query result in MySQL Console does not match the result of PHP's mysql_query()

Tags: php, mysql

My MySQL query returns different results depending on how the query is submitted. When the query is submitted through the MySQL Console results in.

```
mysql> SELECT   `modx`.coverage_nation.id,
    -> `modx`.coverage_nation.name,
    -> `modx`.coverage_national_region.id,
    -> `modx`.coverage_national_region.name
    -> FROM             `modx`.coverage_nation_part
    -> RIGHT JOIN       `modx`.coverage_national_region ON (`modx`.coverage_nati
on_part.nation_regionID = `modx`.coverage_national_region.id)
    -> RIGHT JOIN       `modx`.coverage_nation ON (`modx`.coverage_nation_part.n
ationID = `modx`.coverage_nation.id)
    -> ORDER BY `modx`.coverage_nation.name ASC, `modx`.coverage_national_region
.name ASC;
+----+---------------+------+------+
| id | name          | id   | name |
+----+---------------+------+------+
|  3 | Canada        | NULL | NULL |
| 18 | Chad          | NULL | NULL |
| 17 | Germany       | NULL | NULL |
| 15 | Italy         | NULL | NULL |
|  2 | Mexico        | NULL | NULL |
| 19 | Nigeria       | NULL | NULL |
| 14 | Russia        | NULL | NULL |
| 16 | Spain         | NULL | NULL |
|  1 | United States | NULL | NULL |
+----+---------------+------+------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When the same query is submitted using PHP's `mysql_query` it returns only one row.

```
$query .= "SELECT   `modx`.coverage_nation.id,
`modx`.coverage_nation.name,
`modx`.coverage_national_region.id,
`modx`.coverage_national_region.name
FROM        `modx`.coverage_nation_part
RIGHT JOIN  `modx`.coverage_national_region ON (`modx`.coverage_nation_part.nation_regionID = `modx`.coverage_national_region.id)
RIGHT JOIN  `modx`.coverage_nation ON (`modx`.coverage_nation_part.nationID = `modx`.coverage_nation.id)
ORDER BY `modx`.coverage_nation.name ASC, `modx`.coverage_national_region.name ASC;";

$resultSet = mysql_query($query) or die("query failed ".mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultSet,MYSQL_NUM)) {
    // handle each result here
}
```

Returns only Canada. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I might solve this?

Comment: The same query would normally result in the same result. (unless there are very weird view & user-permissions going on) Much more likely, there's a small error in the PHP code handling it, care to post that?

Comment: If you would find it helpful you can find the full code at https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B2rZ59SOyaKmOWIxZTlhMGItYjVmNi00MDRkLWFjZjctODE2NDM3YzkwMWFi&hl=en&authkey=CPqy7Y4D The query is submitted in the first file, and the result is handled in the second.
https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B2rZ59SOyaKmZDZjYzI2Y2EtMmFiZS00NjQyLTliZWQtMWQ3Y2VkNWZhMDY5&hl=en&authkey=CP3S5_4C

Comment: Wait. The code you posted is not the same code that's running but rather a summation into what you *think* is running?

Comment: The code I posted was snippets taken from the actual code, and the results are what happens when that code in the files is run.

Comment: Post the *actual* code, it might have a bug, a stray ; , a strange break/continue, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in my code somewhere. I sat down and rewrote it and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one field with the names `id` and `name`. Try changing the SELECT portion of your SQL (in the PHP code) to:

```
SELECT `modx`.coverage_nation.id,
`modx`.coverage_nation.name,
`modx`.coverage_national_region.id AS coverage_national_region_id,
`modx`.coverage_national_region.name AS coverage_national_region_name
```

Or something similar so returned fields have distinct names.

Comment: I am using `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultSet,MYSQL_NUM)) {}` so I am dealing with a number not a key string.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the info. What does `mysql_num_rows($resultSet);` return?

Comment: `mysql_num_rows($resultSet)`; returns 1